# gradient decent to compute cp-decomposition of a third order tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorly

I'm trying to do gradient decent to compute the CP decomposition of a third order tensor. I'm using tensorly and I'm a beginner at it. And I don't know how to compute the gradient.

So here is what we have so far:

```
def CP_GD(T, rank, epsilon=1e-5,max_iters=100,lr=1e-2,verbose=True,errors_at_iterations=[]):
    # Initialize A, B and C

    dim1= T.shape[0]
    dim2= T.shape[1]
    dim3= T.shape[2]
    A= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim1,rank]))
    B= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim2,rank]))
    C= tl.tensor(np.random.normal(0,1,[dim3,rank]))


    T_approx_old = tl.kruskal_to_tensor((np.ones(rank),[A,B,C]))# YOUR CODE HERE #
    it = 1
    while True: # repeat until convergence
        # compute gradients wrt A B and C and do a gradient step




        # check for convergence:
        T_approx_new = tl.kruskal_to_tensor((np.ones(rank),[A,B,C]))
        reconstruction_error =  tl.norm(T_approx_new-T)
        errors_at_iterations.append(reconstruction_error)


        if tl.norm(T_approx_old - T_approx_new)/tl.norm(T_approx_old) < epsilon or it > max_iters:
            return (A,B,C)
        if verbose:
            print(it, " - reconstruction error: ",reconstruction_error, "convergence: ", tl.norm(T_approx_old - T_approx_new)/tl.norm(T_approx_old))

        T_approx_old = T_approx_new
        it += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either compute the gradients by hand or, alternatively, use autograd. TensorLy has a backend system that lets you run the computation using NumPy, PyTorch, TensorFlow, etc. If you use any of the backends that support autograd, you can use auto-differentiation to directly get the gradients. Checkout the [notebooks](https://github.com/JeanKossaifi/tensorly-notebooks) for example. For instance, [here](https://github.com/JeanKossaifi/tensorly-notebooks/blob/master/05_pytorch_backend/tucker_decomposition_tensorly_and_pytorch.ipynb), doing Tucker decomposition via gradient descent with TensorLy and PyTorch.